# How linky am I?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Is there a good Data Explorer query to find how "SFF-linky" my answers are in-site?

In more technical terms, for a given user, how many links to SFF.SE are on average in their answers on the site?

Comment: This question is posted in honor of Ted Nelson

Comment: I'm willing to bet that I'm very linky indeed.

Comment: Do you mean how many other questions link to answers you've posted? Or how many links you've included to other answers on the site?

Comment: @Valorum - the latter (but not only to answers, but to ANY site URLs)

Comment: Whoops, missed the "to SFF URLs" bit in that; that changes my numbers more than a little

Comment: Okay, I'm getting a bit mixed up in the language of the question. Are you asking for a way to determine how many links you've put in answers?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks - links in answers, pointing to SFF pages.

Comment: FWIW Here's the full rankings http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/edit/524384

Comment: @Hack-R [Yoink](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4uPOY.gif)

Comment: I feel like I did math, by getting that query to work! I am 0.5121951219512195% linky. :)

Comment: @DVK Ted Nelson is the High Sparrow of http. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [Ask and ye shall receive](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/522684/average-number-of-links-per-answer)

Standard SEDE disclaimers apply:

- Updated once weekly; currently we're about two days behind reality
- Doesn't include deleted posts

Plug your SFF UserId into the box and away you go.

- Mine is **0.453**
- Yours is **0.111**
- Valorum's (since he asked) is **0.047**

Note that this hasn't really been tested, since I'm not inclined to manually count all the links in all of my answers. I'm always welcome to corrections.

An [earlier version of the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/revision/522684/660615/average-number-of-links-per-answer) counted *all* links, but the one above only counts links to SFF.SE (and not meta).

With due credit to Hack-R for doing most of the hard work, you can also check out the [Linky Leaderboard](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/541702/linky-leaderboard), though it isn't very instructive; indeed, the top five are:

- [errantlinguist](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/65294/errantlinguist), with four links in one answer
- [USFBS](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/46019/usfbs), with five links in two answers
- [user137369](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/46144/user137369), with two links in one answer
- The unregistered [Vates](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/46641/vates), also with two links in one answer
- [Tony R](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4980/tony-r), still with two links in one post

To my eternal shame, I am merely the 139th most linky user of the site.

Comment: Apparently I'm not very linky at all :-( Unless you count ***'all links'***, in which case I'm quite linky indeed.

Comment: The `share` link below posts (which is what I usually use for post linking) seems to provide an `http` link. And indeed, if I remove the whole `a href="https` business from your query, the people listed here are way more linky.

Comment: @Cahir Hm, that's annoying. Query updated; thanks

Comment: Mine's **0.79** is that bad?

Comment: @Mooz - Yes. Dreadful. Possibly.

Comment: Oh gosh, and if I include *all* links, then I get **7.15**! What do I win?

Comment: Nothing. That doesnt seep like too much

Comment: @Mooz - It's good if you're into the whole interwebz idea.

Comment: Made a similar query: [Linkyness Leaderboard (including external links)](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/541780/linkyness-leaderboard-including-external-links)